# How To use psexec command remotely?

Tags: pstools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use psexec without admin privileges on target machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/280482/how-to-use-psexec-without-admin-privileges-on-target-machine)

I am trying to access the remote machine using psexec command 
command is : psexec \ remote machine -u [Username] -p [Password] command
but still i am getting Access Denied problem so If any one having solution for this please giving me ans as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one you need permissions. psexec is not a hacking tool - it's a remote administration tool.

Secondly you need ports. 135, 139 and 445 immediately come to mind.  There may be others.